# HTML width at 100% overflowing

Tags: html, css, width

I am trying to set the width of a container to 100% of the page. By itself it seems to be fine, but once I add another `<div>` element in the container, it overflows and the page becomes scrollable. I don't know what's wrong, because I haven't changed the padding and margin settings.

EDIT: the issue only seems to happen on chrome.

EDIT #2: Some people told me that they were not experiencing the same issue on their end, so I uploaded the project files and a screenshot of what I see on my google drive:

[Project files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/183_JryY1S-LWbASR1raRrxF3x88o15zY?usp=sharing)

```css
/* this is my css: */

body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
}

#mainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.genContainer {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.square {
  width: 5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.circle {
  width: 5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">

    <div class="genContainer">

      <div class="person square"></div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no overflow with the code you provided.

Comment: can you try removing the width:5px from the square class style?

Comment: @yinsweet That's weird because I'm getting an overflow for sure.

Comment: @kokila I removed the width:5% and still have the same issue.

Comment: I tried opening the file using safari and it works fine. I'm having the issue with Google Chrome.

Comment: @seddouguim I run the code snippet you provided, I didnt see overflow. Did you see overflow from the code snippet given?

Comment: Yes, i am using the same code. But the issue only seems to happen on chrome.

Comment: i had the same problem then i used this `width: calc(100% - 1px)` or - 2px i am not sure the problem is that the width is 100% and the border adds 2px to it

Comment: Thanks @steve for the comment. As I now know, it's always good to perform a css reset as the accepted answer suggested. This avoid such problems with the borders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unset the padding or margin added by the browser. Some browsers add css by default to your HTML page.
Write this as the first style rule:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This will reset the margin and padding of all elements to 0 and so later in css you can override it.

Comment: I run the code you shared on chrome. There is no overflow.

Comment: add screenshot of what you see on your side

Comment: I uploaded the files used and a screenshot of what I see to my google drive. Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/183_JryY1S-LWbASR1raRrxF3x88o15zY?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
#mainContainer {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

To this:

```
#mainContainer {
    max-width: 100%; /*This limits the container to be 100% regardless of what's within it*/
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```